# Creating an iPA using command line for a Phonegap project

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, command-line, ipa

I used the following instructions http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage for setting up the command line tools for iOS.

But when I try to build the project with $ /path/to/my_new_cordova_project/cordova/debug

I get this:

```
In file included from /Users/jakob/Dropbox/Coding/phonegap/ios_project/ios_project/Classes/AppDelegate.m:28:
/Users/jakob/Dropbox/Coding/phonegap/ios_project/ios_project/Classes/AppDelegate.h:30:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
        ^
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/ios_project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios_project.build/Objects-normal/i386/MainViewController.o ios_project/Classes/MainViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/ios_project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios_project.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o ios_project/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

When I build the project with Xcode everything works fine but I´d prefer to use the command line tools.

I got:
Xcode 5.0
PhoneGap 2.9.1 and I have tried in 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

This error appears probably by using the workspace file. Trying with the xcode project directory should resolve the problem.